# Registros de archivos en C con lista

Tags: c

Estoy realizando una práctica de archivos con una lista Persona que tiene un nombre y edad. Mi problema es que al ejecutarse por primera vez puedo registrar y leer en el archivo, pero al cerrar y volver a ejecutar y quiero leer de nuevo los registros se crashea el programa, es decir, el .exe ha dejado de funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ARCHIVE_PERSONS "persons.bin"

typedef struct Person
{
    int age;
    char *name;
    struct Person *next;
}Person;

void pause(){
    printf("Presiona cualquier tecla para continuar\n");
    getch();
}

void savePerson(Person *newPerson){
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVE_PERSONS,"ab");
    if(!file){
        printf("No se ha podido abrir el archivo\n");
        pause();
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        fwrite(
         newPerson,sizeof(Person),1,file);
    fclose(file);
}

Person * createPerson(int age, char * name){
    Person *newPerson;
    newPerson=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if(!newPerson){
        printf("No se ha podido reserver memoria para hacer el registro");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        newPerson->age=age;
        newPerson->name=name;
        newPerson->next=NULL;
        savePerson(newPerson);
    }
    return newPerson;
}

Person * insertPerson(Person *p, int age, char *name){
    Person *newPerson, *pAux;
    newPerson=createPerson(age,name);
    if(newPerson){
        if(!p)
            p=newPerson;
        else{
            pAux=p;
            while(pAux->next)
                pAux=pAux->next;
            pAux->next=newPerson;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

Person * registerPerson(Person *p){
    int age;
    char *name;
    char aux[50];
    system("cls");

    printf("Ingrese el nombre de la persona\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(aux);
    name=(char*)malloc((sizeof(char)*strlen(aux))+1);
    if(!name){
        printf("no se pudo crear el nombre\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        strcpy(name,aux);
    }
    printf("Ingrese la edad de la persona\n");
    scanf("%i", &age);

    p=insertPerson(p,age, name);
}

void showPerson (){
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVE_PERSONS,"rb");
    Person *newPerson;
    newPerson=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));

    if(!file){
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        pause();
    }

    if(!newPerson){
        printf("No se puede leer archivo\n");
        pause();
    }else{
        system("cls");
        printf("%-10s %-10s\n","Nombre","Edad");
        while(fread(newPerson,sizeof(Person),1,file))
            printf("%-10s %-10i\n",newPerson->name,newPerson->age);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void menu(){
    int op;
    Person *p;
    p=NULL;
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("[1]Ingresar persona\n");
        printf("[2]Mostrar personas\n");
        printf("[3]Salir\n");
        scanf("%i",&op);

        switch(op){
            case 1: p=registerPerson(p); break;
            case 2: showPerson(); break;
            case 3: exit(1); break;
            default: printf("Opcion incorrecta\n");break;
        }
        pause();
    }while(op!=3);
}

int main(){
    menu();
    pause();
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la traza del pete que da?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problema

Tu problema está en la escritura en archivo:

```
fwrite(
 newPerson,sizeof(Person),1,file);
```

Estás escribiendo directamente en el archivo la estructura persona la cuál **no contiene directamente todos los datos** de los que es responsable. Veamos qué aspecto podría tener en memoria (asumiendo punteros de 32 bits):

```
0: |     age   |    name   |    next   |
   |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|
   |         35| 0x00000001| 0x00000002|

1: |name de la estructura en 0|
   |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|
   | M| a| u| r| i| c| i| o|\0|

2: |     age   |    name   |    next   |
   |00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|
   |         21| 0x00000003| 0x00000004|
```

El puntero `newPerson` que escribes en el archivo contiene tres valores, de los cuales dos de ellos son **punteros**:

```
int age;
char *name;
struct Person *next;
```

Es decir: dos de los valores que `Person` maneja, son direcciones de memoria a una zona diferente a la que `newPerson` pertenece; cuando escribes en el archivo estás escribiendo las direcciones de memoria que en **esa ejecución** cada una de las instancias de `Person` estaba usando; cuando recuperas desde archivo estos datos estás recuperando **direcciones de memoria de la ejecución anterior** y las usas en la ejecución presente, lo cuál seguramente provoca tu crash.

#### Solución

No escribas la estructura `Person` directamente, debes [serializarla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializaci%C3%B3n). Para ello, escribe en primer lugar la edad, después la longitud del nombre y para acabar el nombre:

```
int namelen = strlen(newPerson->name);
fwrite(&newPerson->age, sizeof(newPerson->age), 1,       file);
fwrite(&namelen,        sizeof(namelen),        1,       file);
fwrite(newPerson->name, sizeof(char),           namelen, file);
```

En el momento de deserializar:

```
int namelen = 0, age = 0;
Person *newPerson =(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));

// Leer edad y longitud de nombre.
fread(&age,     sizeof(age),     1, file);
fread(&namelen, sizeof(namelen), 1, file);

// Reservar espacio para nombre (incluido caracter nulo).
newPerson->name =(char*)malloc((sizeof(char) * namelen) + 1);
memset(newPerson->name, 0, (sizeof(char) * namelen) + 1);

// Leer nombre.
fread(newPerson->name, sizeof(char), namelen, file);

// ... enlazar con siguiente Person ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta muy bien explicada

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct Person
{
    int age;
    char *name;
    struct Person *next;
}Person;
```

En base a cómo declaras la estructura anterior en tu código existen varios problemas:

```
void showPerson (){
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVE_PERSONS,"rb");
    Person *newPerson;
    newPerson=(Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person)); // (2)

    if(!file){ // (1)
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        pause();
    }

    if(!newPerson){
        printf("No se puede leer archivo\n");
        pause();
    }else{
        system("cls");
        printf("%-10s %-10s\n","Nombre","Edad");
        while(fread(newPerson,sizeof(Person),1,file)) // (4)
            printf("%-10s %-10i\n",newPerson->name,newPerson->age); // (3)
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

**1** Si has tenido problemas para abrir el archivo tu función actual intentará de todas formas leer los registros. Lo lógico sería que al detectar el problema el programa abortase la operación abandonando la función:

```
    if(!file){
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        pause();
        return;
    }
```

Por otro lado no tiene demasiado sentido reservar memoria dinámica para `newPerson` si aún no sabemos si se pueden leer los datos del fichero. Lo normal es hacer la reserva cuando sabemos que podemos realizar la carga:

```
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVE_PERSONS,"rb");

    if(!file){
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        pause();
        return;
    }

    Person *newPerson = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

**2** `newPerson` es una variable local que inicializas con `malloc` y que **nunca** se libera, luego cada vez que se llama a esta función se producen fugas de memoria. Al ser una variable local no es necesario usar punteros, lo cual te permite despreocuparte de la gestión de la memoria.

```
void showPerson (){
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVE_PERSONS,"rb");
    Person newPerson;

    if(!file){
        printf("El archivo esta vacio\n");
        pause();
    }

    system("cls");
    printf("%-10s %-10s\n","Nombre","Edad");
    while(fread(&newPerson,sizeof(Person),1,file))
        printf("%-10s %-10i\n",newPerson.name,newPerson.age);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Si aún así insistes en usar memoria dinámica recuerda usar `free`:

```
void showPerson (){
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen(ARCHIVE_PERSONS,"rb");

    // ...

    }else{
        Person *newPerson = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));

        system("cls");
        printf("%-10s %-10s\n","Nombre","Edad");
        while(fread(newPerson,sizeof(Person),1,file))
            printf("%-10s %-10i\n",newPerson->name,newPerson->age);

        free(newPerson); // <<--- IMPORTANTE
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

**3** Estás guardando una cadena de como mucho 10 caracteres en `new_person->name`... Esto no tendría mayor problema si no fuese porque `new_person->name` no apunta a una dirección de memoria válida. Si el tamaño máximo del nombre está acotado lo más sencillo es hacer que la estructura tenga un tamaño fijo para almacenar el nombre:

```
// Para almacenar hasta 10 caracteres
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 11

typedef struct Person
{
    int age;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    struct Person *next;
}Person;
```

**4** Al leer del fichero estás intentando recuperar la estructura de forma literal. Almacenar una estructura a lo bruto en un fichero no tiene por qué ser problemático salvo que la misma tenga punteros. En tu caso el puntero en cuestión es `next`. Al volcar la estructura al fichero ese puntero almacenará la posición de memoria a la que apunta. Nota que dicha posición no será válida cuando intentes recuperar los datos del fichero.

Lo más limpio para hacer solucionar este problema es dividir la estructura en dos: por un lado una estructura que almacene los datos y otra para la gestión de la lista:

```
typedef struct
{
  int age;
  char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
} Person;

typedef struct node
{
  Person person;
  struct node* next;
} node;

fread(&node->person,sizeof(Person),1,file); // Ahora ya no se leen punteros
fwrite(&node->person,sizeof(Person),1,file); // Ya no se guardan punteros
```

Y luego ya, como notas adicionales:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

`fflush` únicamente debe usarse con buffer de **salida**, su uso con sistemas de entrada puede provocar resultados indeterminados.

un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, y las observaciones por la reserva de memoria